# Concatenating 500 files while removing the first line from each file except the first file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting, cat

I want to create a file which is the result of concatenation of 500 files where the first line of each file except the first file is deleted. I also want the original files unchanged.

I know that `cat` and `sed` should be piped but I cannot wrap my mind around it!

for the moment what I can think of is as follows:

1. Backup the original files.
2. Remove the header from every file using:

   `for x in *.seg; do sed -i 1d ${x}; done`
3. concatenate files using `cat`
4. add the header to the result of step 3.

Can you propose a pipe that can do this while keeping the original files intact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use awk to do this:

```
awk 'NR == FNR || FNR > 1' *.seg > destination
```

For the first file, the total record number `NR` will equal the record number of the current file `FNR`, so all lines will be printed. For other files, only lines after the first will be printed. The output is redirected to a file `destination`.

As you have 500 files, the `FNR > 1` will evaluate to true more often than the `NR == FNR`, so you may want to switch around the order so that short-circuiting takes place:

```
awk 'FNR > 1 || NR == FNR' *.seg > destination
```

When the first part of the `||` is true, there is no need to evaluate the second part. Much faster ;)